# How to change URL package on Ad-mob sites and apps?

Tags: android, admob

First of all, I registered Ad-mob and I entered nothing on URL market http:// now that I've published my application, I'm afraid it will require that URL to monetize my application, so I want to change it again but I can't find where to edit that.

Anyone help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sites & Apps -> Manage settings (on required app) -> Edit (near the title of the app)

youll find it there